# How to update PyQt4 widget locations based on window size?

Tags: python, widget, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm working on developing a PyQt4 application that will require a lot of widgets and I have run into an issue. When you say where to move the widget to (such as: btn.move(100, 100) it moves it properly, but if you resize the window, you can't see it). I'm not sure how to fix this. I don't want to restrict resizing of the window from the user, but I can't have widgets not showing up on screen.

So if the user resizes the program window to 600x600, how can I have widgets automatically change their location?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Qt layout (like a `QVBoxLayout`, `QHBoxLayout`, or a `QGridLayout`)